# show select2 multiple selection outside searchbox

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-select2, jquery-select2-4

Is there any way to show select2 selected items outside search box?
what i have now:
Here is a sample [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/q2hp451y/2/):
[image]
But what i want:
[image]

```
.select2-search-choice{
   width:100%
}
<select multiple id="e1" style="width:300px">
    <option value="AL">Alabama</option>
    <option value="Am">Amalapuram</option>
    <option value="An">Anakapalli</option>
    <option value="Ak">Akkayapalem</option>
    <option value="WY">Wyoming</option>
</select>
```

Comment: im sure there is if there was html and css here

Comment: @Keith i,ll make a demo for that :)

Comment: @Keith here is the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/q2hp451y/2/

Comment: great ill take a look

Comment: do you want to have multiple selections in a column? I can get it outside the container, but I need to know if you want to have it stacked with every selection

Comment: @Keith yes, absolutely.  the same thing that happen now, selected items stacked inside the search box. i need the selected items to be stacked outside the box.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Right now you have it set to overflow: hidden;. Take that off by inherit and then set how far from the top you want your answers to go.

http://jsfiddle.net/q2hp451y/3/

```
.select2-search-choice{
  width:100%
}

.select2-container-multi .select2-choices {
    overflow: inherit;
}

.select2-container-multi .select2-choices .select2-search-choice {
     top: 30px;
     width: 270px;
}
```

Comment: anytime my friend